# How to deploy routes of a react project in iis?

Tags: reactjs, iis, routes

I add a site on iis pointing to the `build` folder of a react app.

When I iniciate that like `localhost:5000/`it works fine, but if I try to go to `localhost:5000/Group` (navigate the routes) it doesn't work and it gives me a 404 error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, given a different name, or is temporarily unavailable.
>
> ...

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Routes from './routes';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar.js';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Simple from './components/SimpleTable.js';
import Group from './components/GroupTable.js';
import SideBarTable from './components/SideBarTable/SideBarTable.js';


const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Simple} />            
            <Route exact path="/Group" component={Group} />
            <Route exact path="/SideBar" component={SideBarTable} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
)


export default Routes;
```

Someone can help?

Comment: Please use search engines to find an IIS related article. IIS does not support `.htaccess`.

Comment: @LexLi so I need to use web.config?

Comment: You usually need a web.config for any IIS site, please the URL Rewrite IIS Module (separate download) to use Rewrite rules. I know nothing about React, so would look for a resource that describes how to use it with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly install the url rewrite extension for the IIS from below [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then you could create a web.config file and add below config setting in it.

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
            <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <!--# Fallback all other routes to index.html-->
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/pms/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: The error continues, it says that is unable to find resource, error 404. I have to do something on iis? I already had URL Rewiter install